# Jquery UI Datepicker wrong date in Safari only

Tags: jquery, safari, datepicker

I have discovered a strange bug where Jquery Ui is displaying the wrong date but only in Safari. For example I set the date to "2014-10-05" but the date picker in Safari is showing it as 2014-10-04. If  I view source it shows the date value as 2014-10-05. If I use a different browser then it shows the correct date.

I have implemented using the following code:

```
<?php $event_date   = "2014-10-05"; ?> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#event_date" ).datepicker();
    $( "#event_date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
    $( "#event_date" ).datepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo $event_date; ?>" );
});
</script>

<label for="event_date">Date</label> 
<input id="event_date" name="event_date" type="text" value="<?php echo $event_date; ?>" /> 
<em>(Event Date: <?php echo $event_date; ?>)</em>
```

This outputs the code as:

```
<input id="event_date" name="event_date" type="text" value="2014-10-05" class="hasDatepicker">
```

But Safari date picker is showing the date as October 4th! Other browser are fine.

You can see this happening in jFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLn0ttc8/

Comment: _I set the date to "**2014-10-05**" but the date picker in Safari is showing it as **2014-10-05**._ What's wrong with that?

Comment: Are you using Safari? I just added a jFiddle link and it was showing the incorrect date in Safari but correct date in Firefox etc.

Comment: Sorry, just realised you said you used Safari. I wonder if this has anything to do with timezones? Can I add screenshots to this?

Comment: See screenshot showing error here: http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-10-04_at_12.32.02_pm-SrYKPMCk.png

Comment: I'm just asking about what you wrote in the question. You set the date to 10-05, and you say it shows 10-05. That's what it's supposed to do. Did you mistype what it shows?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Safari 5.1.10.

Comment: Yes, sorry a typo. That should have been Safari shows it as 2014-10-04.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI highlights both the current date and the one that you gave by the setDate method. It works ok. If you really think something's wrong, try updating jquery-ui

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the issue. This error was happening over a week ago when the dates weren't next to each other. Also, it is showing the wrong selected date in the input field. So when you save the entry (this is part of a form) it incorrectly updates the date field.

Comment: For example, I set the year to 2015 and it showed the date in the input field as 2015-10-05 correctly. HOWEVER if I enter 2015-10-04 as the date it shows 2015-10-03!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm doing this in safari 7.1 http://codepen.io/daniesy/pen/aojKB and it works ok. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks Danut. I tried that but it also gave me the wrong date. I am using Safari 7.0.5. I also had the same result on my iPad.

Comment: See http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-10-04_at_1.14.50_pm-HNMONLh9.png for screenshot of error

Comment: Lol. I tried on iPad and works ok :)) iPhone too. You could try and use some other date picker, like  this one: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/ . It's pretty neat.